# need one model method for different form requests in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have 3 forms in 3 different views

```
<form method="post" action="display/getrow">
<input type="text" name="status">
<input type="submit">
</form>

<form method="post" action="display/getrow">
<input type="text" name="id">
<input type="submit">
</form>

<form method="post" action="display/getrow">
<input type="text" name="name">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

and my database table as 3 columns (id/name/status)

i need a logic to design getrow method in model which can accept any one value (id or name or status) and it has to display row containing that value..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
public function getrow() {

  if (isset($_POST['id'])) {
    // run the query for id
  }
  if (isset($_POST['status'])) {
    // run the query for status
  }
  if (isset($_POST['name']) {
    // run the query for name
  }
}
```

This way you won't have to update your view.

Answer (score 0):

As per your description, 
`display` is your controller,
`getrow` is method.
Just add another parameter which will decide which field to get:
Following is the corrected code:

```
<form method="post" action="display/getrow/status">
<input type="text" name="status">
<input type="submit">
</form>

<form method="post" action="display/getrow/id">
<input type="text" name="id">
<input type="submit">
</form>

<form method="post" action="display/getrow/name">
<input type="text" name="name">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

And in your method:

```
public function getrow($fieldName = '') {
 // In $fieldName you will get either id, status or name.
 if ($fieldName == 'id') {
  // return id
 }
 if ($fieldName == 'status') {
  // return status
 }
 if ($fieldName == 'name') {
  // return name
 }
}
```